# SQL Server Service wont start up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just rebooted my development server but when the server came back up, I can no longer connect to the DB.

I can't even connect from the Management Studio on the server.

So I check the services and the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) are not started. Starting them gives me an error

> Windows could not start the XXX
>   service.

Any ideas?

EDIT: In addition, I ran the service from the command line and noticed this error:

```
2010-11-24 15:38:32.02 Server      Error: 26055, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2010-11-24 15:38:32.02 Server      The SQL Server failed to initialize VIA suppo
rt library [QLVipl.dll]. This normally indicates the VIA support library does no
t exist or is corrupted. Please repair or disable the VIA network protocol. Erro
r: 0x7e.
```

So I went into The Configuration Manager -> Network Configuration -> Protocols and disabed VIA. That allowed me to start it back up again... but I'm worried that is should be enabled...

-Evan

Comment: security? the account starting the service had its password changed

Comment: Thanks Sam. No, no passwords have changed. It's running as Local System by the way. I've got more info now - I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use the event viewer (Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> Event Viewer) to see what actually happened inside. This will give you valuable information for the resolution.

Comment: Thanks Kangkan. I've had a look in there, but there's not much additional info. I ran the service from the command line though. Check out my edit (above) for what I found. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the event viewer and see if there's a reason logged for it not starting. I've seen something similar when the server runs out of available ram.

Since this is your dev server you probably don't need VIA service running, as long as SQL is started you should be ok.

Comment: Appreciate the help Steve! I've had a look in the event viewer, but there's not much additional info. I ran the service from the command line though. Check out my edit (above) for what I found. Thanks again!

Comment: VIA requires specific hardware, likely your dev server isn't configured to use it anyways.  See the wikipedia on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Interface_Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the event log
If these errors is shown

> - The SQL Server failed to initialize VIA support library [QLVipl.dll].
> - TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x7e.

Then only disable your VIA protocol services from both.

1. SQL Native Client
2. SQL Server Network Configuration

After that restart you SQL browser service and SQL server agent service from SQL server configuration manager